# TypeError: Many2many fields library.book.partner.channel_ids and res.partner.channel_ids use the same table and columns

Tags: odoo, odoo-view, odoo-15

I'm trying to develop simple library app with Odoo but I get an error with manytomany relationship.

Here are classes:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    _name = "library.book"
    publisher_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name="library.book.partner", string="Publisher")
    author_ids = fields.Many2many(comodel_name="library.book.partner", relation='library_book_profile_partner_authors', column1='book_id', column2='partner_id', string="Authors")
```

```
class Partner(models.Model):
    _name = "library.book.partner"
    _inherit = "res.partner"
    published_book_ids = fields.One2many("library.book", "publisher_id", string="Published Books")
    book_ids = fields.Many2many("library.book", 'partner_books', 'book_id', 'partner_id', string="Authored Books")
```

This is the error I always  get when installing the app

```
TypeError: Many2many fields library.book.partner.channel_ids and res.partner.channel_ids use the same table and columns
```

Someone can help to solve this please ?

Comment: Can you add your code for the field `library.book.partner.channel_ids`? Because that's seems to be the problem and is not in your example above.

Comment: @CZoellner I haven't any field named channel_ids in my classes

Answer (score 1):

It's the `_inherit = "res.partner"`. Odoo is inheriting the model with a new model name which means it's creating a new table and copying all fields. For `channel_ids` it's trying to create the many2many "join" table, but with the same name as in `res.partner`. That happens because the table name is directly defined in [the field](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/6c72297e72e0936e5564f175dcb1716057e0ac4b/addons/mail/models/res_partner.py#L24) (`mail_channel_partner`).

```py
channel_ids = fields.Many2many('mail.channel', 'mail_channel_partner',
    'partner_id', 'channel_id', string='Channels', copy=False)
```

So to solve the problem you have to "redefine" `channel_ids` on your new model again and change the table name, for example like:

```py
channel_ids = fields.Many2many(relation='mail_channel_library_book_partner')
```

Comment: Thanks CZoellner this solve the issue